# Add ForeignKey field to default User without modifying it?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using the default User model, and created a custom model called Team.  A user can only be on one team, but a team can have many users.  Therefore, I must create the ForeignKey field within the User model.

The thing is, I'm using the default User by simply importing User with `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

What is the easiest way of adding a ForeignKey field into the default User model?  Do I have to extend the default User model?

Or is there a way for me to add a ForeignKey field into Team, and swap the relationship between User and Team?

Comment: This is covered pretty extensively in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). You can either create a profile model or substitute the user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly when you are working with the default Django user model, it's always better to create a custom user model that you can modify easier.  Below is a simple example on how you can modify your User class with the AbtractBaseUser. If you'd like to add a foreign key just use ForeignKey instead of the data types below.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

#    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

Comment: If we inherit from AbstractBaseUser, do we still have to define fields like `email` or `is_active`?  Aren't those fields automatically available since they were inherited?  On that note, do we also have to have `class Meta:` and `def __str__` as well?

Comment: Yes, you still have to define the fields when using AbstractBaseUser, instead of using the User model you're creating a new model.  def_str_ is just how your admin is going to display the username.   You don't have to use the Meta if you want to use the existing database.  In my case I created a new one and moved the users from the old to the new.

Comment: I ended up subclassing AbstractUser instead because then I just have to ad extra fields as needed, and I don't have to define a custom admin model (I just used UserAdmin, with additional fields added)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way of achieving what you want is to use an in-between table. Therefore, you would create your `Team` model as normal and then create another model with two foreign keys to both `User` and `Team`. This is an example, it may change, feel free to change it to your needs.

```
class Group(models.Model):
   group = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Team (models.Model):
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   #your other fields
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I remember reading something about this for ManyToMany fields, but not for ForeignKeys.  You'd also need a `through='Group'` right?